# codeigniter pagination not working as expected

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I tried a lot but cant seem to figure out this, any help appreciated. My articles have votes, and I have a page which is supposed to show most voted articles. Am using codeigniter btw.
The controller:

```
function most_voted()
    {
        $per_page = 3;
        $cur_page = $this->uri->segment(4);
        /*
        if($cur_page == "") $cur_page = 1;
        else $cur_page = (integer)$cur_page;
        */
        $offset = ($cur_page - 1) * $per_page;
        if($offset < 0) $offset = 0;
        $this->load->model('article_model');
        $result_rows = $this->article_model->GetMostVoted($per_page,$cur_page);
        $total_rows = sizeof($result_rows) + 10;
        echo "total rows is : ".$total_rows.'<br>';
        echo "cur page is   : $cur_page <br>";

        //$this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'articles/most_voted/page/';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['num_links'] = 3;
        $config['first_link'] = '<<First';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Last>>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '< Previous';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next >';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);


        $data['articles'] = $result_rows;
        $data['view_file_name'] = 'articles/all_articles_view';
        $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
```

The model :

```
function GetMostVoted($limit,$offset)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('votes','desc');
        $q=$this->db->get('cgh_articles',$limit,$offset);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($q->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

The problem :
Issue is that though I get pagination like 
 < Previous 1 2 3 4 5 Next > 
but clicking on 2 goes to url : page/3
clicking on 3 goes to url : page/6
clicking on 4 goes to url : page/9 
and so on.
I want a click on 2 to go to page/2, 3 to page/3, and so on. Any suggestions as to whats going wrong?

If you need any more info, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The way the pagination class works is that it returns the item at which the page should start.

For example, url : hostanme/controller/page/9 means that the page should be rendered starting with the 9th most voted article. See the example in the [codeigniter documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html).

Also, you have `$total_rows = sizeof($result_rows) + 10;`. Why is that ?

Comment: thanks, jd. sizeof($result_rows) + 10 is just an integer that I've kind of hardcoded for the time being. I'll be replacing it with the actual number of results returned. So, you mean that the default ci pagination will not give me what I wannted ?

Comment: It sounds like you want something different. But if you think of it, the way the Codeigniter library works is good practice: it tells you exactly at which item you should be starting the rendering of your page, so you don't have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: I see your point and now understand how the pagination library works (Though, I dint see this mentioned anywhere in the ci user docs). But honestly, I woudn't want to have that on my site, coz if it did confuse me, it would confuse my end user even more. From a user pov, most of the sites, forums take you to page 3 if you click on 3, 7 = 7 and so on, even SO. So I guess I'll have to write something that does it different to ci ?

Comment: As per what I read on this ci forum (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/126839/), the pagination doc is incorrect, so I guess, if you are facing an issue similar to mine, you need to re-write/modify the pagination lib

Comment: I just found this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274357/sql-counting-number-of-matching-results-when-using-a-limit-query) which might be of interest to anyone trying to figure out if it is necessary to access the db twice to get $config['total_rows']. As for my original need, I'll be writing my own pagination lib / modifying the original lib

Comment: just keep in mind that the number is the new offset, not the page number

Answer (score 1):

There is an [excellent tutorial for this on nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination/).